# Can't get jQuery div to sit over wrap div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Have a problem with the navigation when scrolling down. It puts itself behind the `.post` class.

Scrolled down:

[image]

---

Not Scrolled down:
[image]

jQuery:

```
var num = $('.header').height();

$(window).bind('scroll', function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > num) {
        $('.menu').addClass('fixed-nav');
        $('.wrapper').before($('.menu'));
    } else { 
        $('.menu').removeClass('fixed-nav'); 
        $('.menu-menu-container').prepend($('.menu'));
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
.post {
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    font-size: 16px;
}

/* Navigation style */

.nav {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 60%;
}

.nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
    border-bottom: 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1) solid;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.7;
    text-transform: uppercase; 
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px; /* future proofing */
    -khtml-border-radius: 10px; /* for old Konqueror browsers */
}
```

URL:

http://www.bradlyspicer.net

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

add z-index for div#header {

}

```
div#header {
z-index: 999;
}
```

Comment: post your code to jsfiddle then, then I will be able to investigate and fix it

Comment: Bit difficult as I'm using Wordpress hooks etc. I added the URL above

Answer (score 0):

Your stacking context is broken. Inside of Div#header you have nav#navigation. Outside div#header you have div#wrapper.

You can't have div#wrapper scroll below nav#navigation but above div#header. Any element outside div#wrapper is either above or below div#wrapper and its children (without some significant modifications that change the stacking context).

Stacking order isn't as simple as "Higher Z-Index = On Top". Stacking takes into account the location of the element in the element tree, opacity, positioning, and a number of other factors.

[Philip Walton wrote a good article about z-index and stacking.](http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/)

As for a solution, remove nav#navigation from div#header and put it inside the body, and add "position: absolute;" to the nav#navigation element. The result should look something like this.

```
<body>
<div id="header">...</div>
<div id="wrapper">...</div>
<nav id="navigation" style="position:absolute;">...</nav>
</body>
```